# Django jQuery File Upload stopped working on update

Tags: django, jquery-file-upload

I have lost my file upload app.  I followed the site below and had it working great.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html

I am not sure if it was updating to Django 2.0.2 or the latest update for jQuery File Upload, but it is not working now.

This is the error I get in the view when I check if form is valid.

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>file<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Here is the html:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" multiple style="display: none" data-url="{% url 'upload:index' %}" data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
```

Yes I updated the URL and the Form.

Model:

```
class Upload ( models.Model ):
    title = models.CharField ( max_length = 255, blank = True )
    file = models.FileField ( upload_to = 'uploads/%Y/%m/%d/' )
```

Form:

```
class UploadForm ( forms.ModelForm ):

    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = ['file']
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not certain how I got it to work again but here are a couple changes that I made and it once again works.

I think it was adding the form_class to the view - not sure why it would change anything?

```
class BasicUploadView ( View ):

    form_class = UploadForm

    def post ( self, request, *args, **kwargs ):

        form = self.form_class ( request.POST, self.request.FILES )

        if form.is_valid ():
```

Hope this helps - though don't ask me why?

Cheers.